# Whats this musics genre?

Tags: identify-this-genre, genre

I just saw a video and was fascinated by its music. Sadly Shazam is not recognizing the song. So I want to have a look at some titles whose genre is the same. The problem is: I don't know the genre. Can someone tell me the genre's name?

[Link to music](https://instaud.io/23BV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard this called 'Epic' music (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_music) in reference to modern scores in films and video games (Hans Zimmer for example). The percussion reminds me of something Martin O'Donnell would have made for the Halo franchise. The truth is it isn't an official 'genre'. It takes elements from pop/rock/electronic music, classical music, classic film scores, and even cultural music like Gregorian chants or African tribal rhythms.

The short answer is it is simply modern film/video game/media scores. This specific composition I would say is electronic music with orchestral and traditional rock percussion influence.